# Delphi TextRect to center text on a canvas: TTextFormat

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to follow [this example](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=56814.0) on how to use `TextRect()` to center text on a Canvas, but it seems to be outdated and doesn't work because there's no `TTextStyle` anymore. Instead, `TextRect()` takes something called `TTextFormat`.

The original code from that thread:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  ts: TTextStyle;
begin
    Canvas.Font.Size:=22;
    Canvas.Font.Color:=clRed;
    ts := Canvas.TextStyle;
    ts.Alignment := taCenter;
    ts.Layout := tlCenter;
    Canvas.TextRect(Rect(100, 100, 300, 300), 0, 0, 'Hello', ts);  // Rect within text is centered, dummy x, dummy y, text, text style
end;
```

The [TextRect documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextRect) doesn't provide any examples of how to use `TTextFormat`, including [the `FrameRect` example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Alexandria/en/FrameRect_(Delphi)).

I followed some links for [`TextFlags`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.TextFlags) and there's no Alignment flags there.

I'm guessing it's an array with flags now, but what are the flags for Center Alignment, both horizontally and vertically? How would this example be updated?

Comment: `TCanvas` in Delphi has *never* had a `TextStyle` property, and `TextRect()` has *never* had a `TTextStyle` overload, in either VCL or FMX.  The example you have shown comes from FreePascal/Lazarus instead. That is why you were having trouble translating it to Delphi. Different frameworks, different APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, in Windows, you cannot draw to a canvas in a button's click handler. You can only draw to a canvas in the window's paint handler.

To try this out, create a new VCL application and add an `OnPaint` handler to the main form:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin

  // Fill entire window with white background colour

  Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  Canvas.FillRect(ClientRect);

  // Draw text in the middle

  Canvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
  Canvas.Font.Size := 32;

  var R := ClientRect;
  var S := 'Hello, World!';

  Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);

end;
```

First, we fill the entire window with white colour. This is our background colour.

Then, we draw our text using

```pascal
Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);
```

The `tfCenter` flag instructs the function to centre the text horisontally. The `tfVerticalCenter` flag instructs it to centre it vertically, which is only possible if we also specify the `tfSingleLine` flag. The `tfEndEllipsis` flag is optional; it will truncate the text with an ellipsis (...) if the text doesn't fit in the rectangle.

(For bonus points, add a one-line `OnResize` handler that calls `Invalidate` to redraw the entire window when it is resized.)

[image: Screenshot]

The VCL canvas' `TextRect` function is implemented using the Win32 [`DrawText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawtext) function, which is very well documented.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In my case, unlike the example (which is painting on a form), I'm actually painting on a `TImage`'s Canvas. For that I'm using `Rect(x1,y1,x2,y2)`. I took your TF array as follows: 
`imgCanvas.Canvas.TextRect(Rect(100, 100, 300, 300), 'text', [tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);`
This is giving the error `There is no overloaded version of TextRect that can be called with these arguments.`

Comment: @geneb.: Let's consult [the documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextRect). The only overload which has the text format parameter is the first one, so we need to use that one. Now, this is declared as `procedure TextRect(var Rect: TRect; var Text: string; TextFormat: TTextFormat = [])`. The **var** means that the argument you pass must be a variable. It's not enough with a value of the right type; it must be a variable. (Under the hood, you pass a pointer to the variable.) So you need to declare variables `R` and `S` as I do and pass them.

Comment: For example, `var R := Rect(100, 100, 300, 300); var S := 'text'; imgCanvas.Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [...])`.

Comment: (Nitpick: `[tfSingleLine, tfVerticalCenter, tfCenter, tfEndEllipsis]` is not an [array](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Arrays), but a [set](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Sets).)

Comment: Got it now. Thanks a lot Andreas.

Comment: @geneb.: That's because the function sometimes needs to *modify* the rect and/or string (depending on the flags you pass). Hence, you need to pass a pointer to a variable. The Microsoft documentation about DrawText explains the details.